# Is Captain America back with Iron Man and the Avengers?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming* while Happy (Jon Favreau) is loading the plane at Avengers Tower he mentions a "prototype of Cap's new shield".

Does that mean Captain America is back with the Avengers and whatever was between Tony and Steve is over?

Comment: the gym teacher claims Cap is "a war criminal or something", so it's unlikely he's back with the Avengers yet.

Comment: @KutuluMike I was going to say the same

Comment: @KutuluMike In AoS the general public (and the government) often think the same thing about SHIELD.

Comment: @OrangeDog What's AoS ?

Comment: @LocustHorde Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## We don't know.

The last we saw in the MCU of Captain America was in *Captain America: Civil War* with Steve Rogers apparently escaping/being broken out of prison [the Raft] and going underground.

It's possible that Cap has continued crime fighting without a shield and Tony is making a new one *just in case* Steve comes back into the fold.

We don't even know that the "Cap" referred to in *Homecoming* is Steve Rogers. Captain America is a **title**...not a person's name...it was conferred upon him and, at least in the comics, it has been held by a number of other people including Sam (Falcon) Wilson.

It's possible (although not likely) that there's another Captain America for whom the new shield is being created.

We probably won't find out until *Infinity War* in 2018.

Comment: Captain Marvel might also like having a shield.

Comment: Captain Marvel could probably make one out of thin air tho

Comment: @LiquidSame Carol Danvers has that power?

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen her do it in a comics many years ago, I'll try to see if I can find it

Comment: It is as Binary that she can make a shield using Gravity waves. She doesn't have that power as just Captain Marvel so yeah guess she could use a shield.

Comment: It also might have been a prototype that Tony/whoever was working on before Civil War, and has just been retained since then.

Comment: For those not familiar with the movies, could you put the title of the film where "Steve Rogers escap[es] prison"?  (I'm one of those in the dark)

Comment: It's at the end of *Civil War*...edited answer to include.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Cap wasn't breaking *himself* out of prison.  Just others.

Comment: Maybe some refresh now after the Infinity war, since it's the accepted answer?

Answer (score 11):

There's not even remotely enough information from this single line of dialogue to ascertain the relationship between Cap and Iron Man.  At the end of Civil War we see that Tony at least still cares somewhat for Steve, and he might even be supplying him with new tech.  However, since Steve and his gang are now criminals he is probably doing it under the table.  IE, being secret about helping them out but publicly denouncing them.

But again, there's just not enough information to go on just from this one line.

Comment: Yep bang-on, we don't have anywhere close to enough information to reach any conclusions from that one line - heck, it could even have been a prototype that Tony was working on prior to the events of Civil War

Answer (score 3):

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming (2017)* there is a line a teacher in school says to the kids. It's something like:

> "Kids listen to Captain America, even though he's a war criminal now or something".

So I'm assuming that they still didn't smooth things out with Cap.

Answer (score 2):

In the final scene of Captain America: Civil War, we see that Captain America has sent Tony a letter, which is ended by saying 'if you need me, I'll be there'. That suggests that if he was needed he would be open to being calling upon. I imagine he'll be back, particularly if they end up battling someone like Thanos.

Answer (score 0):

We simply don't know.

However.

We hear from several sources that Cap is a persona non grata to the general population.

The gym teacher, whilst playing his video, says that he's "pretty sure this guy's a war criminal now".

That said, Stark could be maintaining some ties with his old buddy, and there's enough material in Civil War to indicate they'd gang back up if the going got rough.

Also, take into account what Paulie said: There have been many holders of the ***Title*** Captain America, and it could've also been for Captain Marvel, who we know will be the tittle character of one of MCU's upcoming movies.